# Is there a way to change/define state in using an emptyComposeRule?

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, state

I have a page that uses both Views and Compose and I'm trying to create an automated test for it.

Referring to https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing. You are able to define a state under setContent. However using emptycomposerule, setContent doesn't exist, so how would you be able to determine or change state?

```
@Test
    fun myTest() {
        // Start the app
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                MainScreen(uiState = fakeUiState, /*...*/)
            }
        }

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Continue").performClick()

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Welcome").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
```

An example:

```
@get:Rule
val activityRule = lazyLaunchRule()

@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createEmptyComposeRule()

activityRule.setSession(
    "session.json"
)
activityRule.launch()

composeTestRule.onNode(preview).assertIsDisplayed()
<--- insert state change here --->
```

Code that's trying to get hit, it currently just never sets it to Open

```
if (drawerState == viewModel.Closed) {
    drawerState.setValue(DrawerValue.Closed)
} else {
    drawerState.setValue(DrawerValue.Open)
}
```

The state is already set to default which is closed. I tried, mocking the viewmodel and changing state but it doesn't seem to trigger this state change. It is also fine to have it open from the start but there doesn't seem to be a way to set the state up from using emptyComposeRule